# Bishop's opening - avoiding positional lines as Black after 2...Nf6 3. d3

Tags: opening, bishops-opening

I'm currently experimenting `1...e5` against `1.e4` aiming at the Petrov but I sometimes encounter Bishop's opening `2. Fc4` to which I reply `2...Nf6`.

If White play `3. Nc3`, I have some ideas, but if they play `3.d3`, it's another story since after `3...Nc6`, White can play `4.Nf3` that leads to a positional Two Knight's. 
And playing `3...Bc5` leads to a Guoco Pianissimo which I want to avoid at all cost.

Are there some interesting lines here for Black considering the above ? Even if it's slighty inferior. Thanks

```
rnbqkb1r/pppp1ppp/5n2/4p3/2B1P3/3P4/PPP2PPP/RNBQK1NR b KQkq - 0 3
```

Comment: [1.e4 e5 2.Bc4 f5](https://www.365chess.com/eco/C23_Bishop%27s_opening_Calabrese_counter-gambit) may not be the world's soundest opening, but at least you avoid the positional lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to play as black after Bishop's Opening: 1. e4 e5; 2. Bc4](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15918/what-to-play-as-black-after-bishops-opening-1-e4-e5-2-bc4)

Comment: How could it be a duplicate ? My question is more specific.

Comment: @loukios your question being more specific wouldn't oppose that, *if the answers to that question would cover your specific question in sufficient detail*, but (IMHO) they don't, so I vote to leave open.

Answer (score 5):

3...c6 is in my opinion by far the best move here. Usually white would continue with something like 4.Nf3 Be7 5.O-O (5.Nxe5 Qa5+) d6. 5...d6 is a more solid choice but 5...d5 is another option if you want to blast open the center quicker. For a nice game with 5...d6 played, take a careful look through Gelfand - Yusupov, Munich 1994.

Answer (score 2):

The typical response is 3...c6, and eventually ... d5. With the nice pawn center and active pieces you can certainly get something sharp/tactical from that.

Answer (score 1):

I would play d5 in this position.  It attacks white's center and gives you a lead in development.  The only problem is that it's the reverse Scotch Opening, which means the more aggressive Max Lange Attack isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is playing 3...c6. It typically leads to unbalanced positions, and is objectively fine for Black. Your plan is to push ...d5, posing White with problems in the centre. A sample line:

3...c6 4.Nf3 d5 5.exd5 cxd5 6.Bb5+ Bd7 7.Bxd7+ Nxd7, and Black is completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be fooled by the 3...c6 answers.  3...c6 4.Bb3 d5 5.Qe2 and Black is not mixing it up.
If you want to avoid slow play strike immediately with 3...d5